# Python unix socket server recieves same data from client multiple times

Tags: python, ruby, sockets, unix-socket

I am trying to communicate between ruby and python through unix sockets, and i need multithreaded python server to respond to many ruby clients. All work fine except 1 thing, that i send message from client only once, but the server recieves it 2 times somehow.

What maybe the problem?

Here's my python server code:

```
import socket
import os
import threading
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create a file handler
handler = logging.FileHandler('python_server.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create a logging format
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(handler)

class ThreadedServer(object):

    def __init__(self, socket_path):
        if os.path.exists(socket_path):
            os.remove(socket_path)

        logger.info("Opening socket...")
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server.bind(socket_path)

    def listen(self):
        size = 1024
        logger.info("Listening...")
        try:
            while True:
                datagram, address = self.server.recvfrom(1024)
                threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (self.server, datagram, address, logger)).start()
        finally:
            logger.info("Shutting down...")
            self.server.close()
            os.remove("/tmp/python_socket_server")
            logger.info("Done")

    def listenToClient(self, server, datagram, address, logger_obj):
        while True:
            try:
                if datagram:
                    logger_obj.info('Recieved message from client %s', address)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    server.sendto(bytes("I hear you buddy", 'UTF-8'), address)
                    logger_obj.info('Responded to client %s', address)
                else:
                    raise ValueError('Client disconnected')
            except:
                return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket_path = "/tmp/python_socket_server"
    ThreadedServer(socket_path).listen()
```

My ruby client:

```
require "socket"

SERVER_SOCKET = "/tmp/python_socket_server"

threads = []

5.times do 
    threads << Thread.new do 
        socket = Socket.new :UNIX, :DGRAM
        socket.bind Socket.pack_sockaddr_un("")

        socket.send("Hello server, can you hear me?\n", 0, Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(SERVER_SOCKET))
        puts socket.recvfrom(1024)

        socket.close
    end
end

threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

And the log looks like this:

```
2018-03-05 22:08:43,566 - __main__ - INFO - Opening socket...
2018-03-05 22:08:43,567 - __main__ - INFO - Listening...
2018-03-05 22:08:45,572 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c0'
2018-03-05 22:08:45,573 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c1'
2018-03-05 22:08:45,573 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c2'
2018-03-05 22:08:45,574 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c3'
2018-03-05 22:08:45,574 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c4'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,574 - __main__ - INFO - Responded to client b'\x00025c3'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,575 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c3'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,577 - __main__ - INFO - Responded to client b'\x00025c1'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,577 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c1'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,577 - __main__ - INFO - Responded to client b'\x00025c2'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,577 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c2'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,578 - __main__ - INFO - Responded to client b'\x00025c0'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,578 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c0'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,579 - __main__ - INFO - Responded to client b'\x00025c4'
2018-03-05 22:08:50,579 - __main__ - INFO - Recieved message from client b'\x00025c4'
2018-03-05 22:08:56,437 - __main__ - INFO - Shutting down...
2018-03-05 22:08:56,438 - __main__ - INFO - Done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `while True:` at the start of your `listenToClient` method. (If you just remove that line, it should work as you expect it to.)

You get a datagram already in `listen`, so your `listenToClient` only needs to handle it and return data to the other end. (In that way, it should probably be called `handleClientRequest` or `respondToClient` or similar, that might be more appropriate.)

With the `while True:` in place, it's going back to the start of that loop, where `datagram` is still set to the same value, so it's trying to reply to the other side once again. (Those threads probably get stuck there, since the other side stopped receiving.)

I hope that helps!